# MySql Update JSON Value

Tags: mysql, json

I have a column in a mysql database called `params`, this contains json data. See sample below;

```
{
  "menu_text": 1,
  "menu-meta_description": "My Website",
  "enable_page_title": "0",
  "page_title_heading": "h2"
}
```

I only want to update the `enable_page_title` key to `1`, for every record in the table. I need to leave all other json values intact.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON modification function `JSON_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set):

```
select json_set(js, "$.enable_page_title", 1) new_js from t;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c3grKximxmGUPha5iK5otz/2)**:

```
with t as (
    select '{
        "menu_text": 1,
        "menu-meta_description": "My Website",
        "enable_page_title": "0",
        "page_title_heading": "h2"
    }' js
)
select json_pretty(json_set(js, "$.enable_page_title", 1)) new_js from t;

| new_js                                                                                                                |
| -------------------------------------------- |
| {
  "menu_text": 1,
  "enable_page_title": 1,
  "page_title_heading": "h2",
  "menu-meta_description": "My Website"
} |
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the `js` part for?

Comment: @TheOrdinaryGeek: `js` is the name of the column that contains your json data. I added a demo to my answer for your reference.